# How to view multiple fields as a single field in salesforce report?

Tags: reporting

How can I view multiple fields as a single field in reports?For example,To view billing street,city and country as a single address field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we use Custom object we will be able to see a single field as address for account, for standard Object like account it will show the different field like billing street, city. On Standard object you won't be able to combine all the fields to address field.

Would suggest to create separate fields like Billing address or mailing address and use it in custom reports.